# How to get rid of did_you_mean warnings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I had to update my bundler and since then I got some warning messages that I'm not sure how to get rid off. I tried to revert to the bundler version that has been used according to my Gemfile.lock, but that's not working.
Any ideas?

```
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:53: warning: Insecure world writable dir /mnt/c in PATH, mode 040777
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/did_you_mean/version.rb:2: warning: already initialized constant DidYouMean::VERSION
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.3.0/lib/did_you_mean/version.rb:2: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/did_you_mean/jaro_winkler.rb:63: warning: already initialized constant DidYouMean::JaroWinkler::WEIGHT
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.3.0/lib/did_you_mean/jaro_winkler.rb:63: warning: previous definition of WEIGHT was here
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/did_you_mean/jaro_winkler.rb:64: warning: already initialized constant DidYouMean::JaroWinkler::THRESHOLD
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.3.0/lib/did_you_mean/jaro_winkler.rb:64: warning: previous definition of THRESHOLD was here
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/name_error_checkers/variable_name_checker.rb:9: warning: already initialized constant DidYouMean::VariableNameChecker::NAMES_TO_EXCLUDE
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.3.0/lib/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/name_error_checkers/variable_name_checker.rb:9: warning: previous definition of NAMES_TO_EXCLUDE was here
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/name_error_checkers.rb:5: warning: already initialized constant DidYouMean::NameErrorCheckers
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.3.0/lib/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/name_error_checkers.rb:5: warning: previous definition of NameErrorCheckers was here
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/method_name_checker.rb:7: warning: already initialized constant DidYouMean::MethodNameChecker::NAMES_TO_EXCLUDE
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.3.0/lib/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/method_name_checker.rb:7: warning: previous definition of NAMES_TO_EXCLUDE was here
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/did_you_mean.rb:34: warning: already initialized constant DidYouMean::SPELL_CHECKERS
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.3.0/lib/did_you_mean.rb:87: warning: previous definition of SPELL_CHECKERS was here
```

Thank you,

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running

`bundle clean --force`

Then bundle again